# Make div tag visible using java-script or Ajax render option in JSF

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2

Currently I’m facing problem with the div component after add the ajax render in the suggestioinField component the div display change to none.How to make it the page to stay in the same page even thought after its render to the action.

This is the javascript function i used to hide and show the divident

```
function AddShow(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";}
```

Add Button to show div tag :

```
<h:commandButton type="button" id="cmdadd1" value="#{message.btn__list_add}" onclick="AddShow('Add')" immediate="true"/>
```

JSF Page-Div Content

```
<div id="Add" display:none;"> 
  <h:outputLabel value="#{message.label_listA }" />                 
  <o:suggestionField id="addvalA"  value="#{MainAction.CodeAdd}" customValueAllowed="false"
   manualListOpeningAllowed="true"  autoComplete="true" suggestionMinChars="1   onchange="O$.ajax.request(this,event,{ execute: 'frmList: addvalA ', listener: ‘MainAction.doSelectCodeAdd', render: 'frmList' })"onkeydown="O$.ajax.request(this,event,{listener: 'MainAction.doResetA'})" onblur="O$.ajax.request(this,event,{render:'frmList'})" ><o:dropDownItems value="#{MainAction.doCodeAdd}"/> </o:suggestionField>                            

   <h:commandButton  id="cmdAddConfirm"  value="#{message.btn_create}"  >
       <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{MainAction.doConfirmAdd}"/>                           
  </h:commandButton>


  </div>
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following to your js file I assume that you got jQuery (from primefaces) , and anyway the `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data)...` is the important part ...

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
        if (data.status === "success") {
            if(data.source.id  === "cmdAddConfirm"){
                AddShow('Add');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

short explanation :

On each ajax call the `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` will be called , inside it only after it was ended successfully and only if the call was made from `cmdAddConfirm` button , you will call your js function to set the display to block